# Method Interceptor not being called in Test

Tags: java, spring, aop, spring-aop

My method interceptor isn't called in test context. the test context is configured for my test class: with `@ContextConfiguration(locations = {"classpath:testContext.xml"})` and I have a method interceptor:

```
public class MyMethodInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {

@Override
public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
    System.out.println("invocation >>>> " + invocation);
}
```

and it's configured in my context.xml file like this:

```
<bean id="myMethodInterceptor" class="path.to.interceptor.MyMethodInterceptor"/>

<aop:config>
    <aop:advisor pointcut="@within(path.to.annotation.MyAnnotation)"
                 advice-ref="myMethodInterceptor" order="10"/>
</aop:config>
```

my expectation is in my test when I call a method with `MyAnnotation` the interceptor is being called, but it will not. I'm using JUnit 4.12

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> when I call a method with `MyAnnotation`

This will never work, neither in a test nor in production code. The reason is simple: A method interceptor and use of the `@within()` pointcut designator are diametrically opposed to each other:

`@within()` intercepts everything (i.e. in Spring AOP method executions) inside **annotated classes**, while according to your description you want to intercept **annotated methods**.

The solution would be to either use `@annotation(path.to.annotation.MyAnnotation)` and annotate all target methods, or to continue using `@within(path.to.annotation.MyAnnotation)`, but annotate target classes instead.